# Will PXE boot a blank hard drive?

Tags: installation, pxe

If I have a blank hard drive and a computer that is set to boot from PXE NIC will it download the OS to the hard drive that is blank or does it need a special format for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PXE will boot a computer with a blank hard drive, in fact it will but a computer without a hard drive.  It will not, necessarily, copy the OS to the hard drive.  The OS that gets booted may be an OS installer, which would then copy the OS to the hard drive, but its up to the OS do that.